# Changing style of Leaflet Realtime geoJson features

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have a leaflet map using leaflet-realtime to display and update a position, polygon and line from a geoJson source (data is the position and field of view from an airborne camera). I want to change the style of the line and polygon from the default blue. I understand the leaflet-realtime extends L.geojson so I thought the following code should work but I get *options.style* is not a function. I have been looking at other examples to try and do this but have spent the day frustrated.

```
var lineStyle = {
    color: 'black',
    weight: 5,
    opacity: 0.5
}

los = L.realtime({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1/geojson/los2.geojson',
    crossOrigin: true,
    type: 'json'
}, {
    interval: 1 * 500,
    style: lineStyle
   
}).addTo(map);

los.on('update', function(){
  
    map.flyTo(
            [this._features.los.geometry.coordinates[1][1],
             this._features.los.geometry.coordinates[1][0]]
           
       )
    
});
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes options.style must be a function - look at:
https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#geojson-style

Change your code:

```
var lineStyle = {
    color: 'black',
    weight: 5,
    opacity: 0.5
}

los = L.realtime({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1/geojson/los2.geojson',
    crossOrigin: true,
    type: 'json'
}, {
    interval: 1 * 500,
    style: function() { return lineStyle; }
   
}).addTo(map);

los.on('update', function(){
  
    map.flyTo(
            [this._features.los.geometry.coordinates[1][1],
             this._features.los.geometry.coordinates[1][0]]
           
       )
    
});
```